# OnClick Event binding in React.js while code is in variable

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to generate click event for button. I have put button in variable to map different buttons for service but click event is not working. Its giving "Cannot read property 'addCompnay' of undefined.".
Can someone help me with this.

```
   class Sidebar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

       super(props);

       this.state = {

          allServices:[],

       }

       this.addCompnay = this.addCompnay.bind(this);


  }

  addCompnay() {

      alert("asd");

  }

  render() {

  var sidebarpagedata = this.state.allServices.companies.map(function(sidebarpagedata, index){
<Button type="button" className="default pull-right" onClick={this.addCompnay} >Apply Now</Button>

 })

 return (

  {sidebarpagedata}

 );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
  render() {
     var sidebarpagedata = this.state.allServices.companies.map((sidebarpagedata, index) => {
         <Button type="button" className="default pull-right" onClick={this.addCompnay} >Apply Now</Button>
    })

    return (
        {sidebarpagedata}
    );

}
```

Comment: What you have changed ?

Comment: because of this code, Click event is generated even if we have not clicked on element. While page scroll or rendering event is called automatically

Answer (score 2):

You got 2 problems with this code:

```
  var sidebarpagedata = this.state.allServices.companies.map(function(sidebarpagedata, index){
<Button type="button" className="default pull-right" onClick={this.addCompnay} >Apply Now</Button>

 })
```

Your map function is has a different `this` context, either user an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) or pass the `this` explicitly:

```
var sidebarpagedata = this.state.allServices.companies.map((sidebarpagedata, index) => {
<Button type="button" className="default pull-right" onClick={this.addCompnay} >Apply Now</Button>

 })
```

The second problem here is that you are missing a `return`, change it to this:

```
var sidebarpagedata = this.state.allServices.companies.map((sidebarpagedata, index) => {
 return (<Button type="button" className="default pull-right" onClick={this.addCompnay} >Apply Now</Button>)

 })
```

Comment: because of this code, Click event is generated even if we have not clicked on element. While page scroll or rendering event is called automatically

Answer (score 0):

In the following case you don't need to bind the function if using an arrow function.

```js
class Sidebar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

       super(props);

       this.state = {

          allServices:[],
       }
  }

  addCompnay = () => {
      alert("asd");
  }

  render() {

  var sidebarpagedata = this.state.allServices.companies.map(function(sidebarpagedata, index){
<Button type="button" className="default pull-right" onClick={() => this.addCompnay()} >Apply Now</Button>

 })

 return (

  {sidebarpagedata}

 );

}
```